# Jest test that value is set in .finally() block of fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, jestjs

I am testing a Vue component's method that performs a basic `fetch`, and updates a data value in the `.finally()` block of that `fetch`. I can confirm that my test reaches that `.finally()` block, but the data value is never updated.

My method is:

```js
updateProfile () {
  fetch(updateProfileEndPoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {email: test@test.com, id: 1234, name: 'bob},
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.errorField = true;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.profileUpdated = true;
      });
```

In my Jest test, I have:

```js
const wrapper = mount(ProfileComponent, { store,
  data () {
    return {
      profileUpdated: false,
    };
   },
 });

 global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
   Promise.resolve({
     profileUpdate: 'complete',
   })
 );

 wrapper.vm.updateProfile();
 expect(wrapper.vm.profileUpdated).toBe(true);
```

However, `profileUpdated` remains `false`. Strangely, if I `console.log(this.profileUpdate)` in that method, the updated value `true` does log. However, my tests still receive `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion occurs before the asynchronous `fetch` call actually completes.

One solution is to return the `fetch` result (a `Promise`) from `updateProfile()`, allowing the test to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the call:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    updateProfile() {
      return fetch(...).catch(...).finally(...)
    }   
  }
}

// MyComponent.spec.js                           
it('updateProfile() sets profileUpdated flag', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(...)
    
  await wrapper.vm.updateProfile()
  expect(wrapper.vm.profileUpdated).toBe(true)
})
```